# Выбор функции потерь для обработки звукового сигнала с применением нейронных сетей

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, fft, цос

в данный момент работаю над нейронной сетью которая сжимает аудиоданные, если вы имеет хорошие статьи в этой области или работы (ссылки на githab) не могли ли бы вы поделиться.
А теперь к проблеме. Построил нейронную сеть, вроде бы обучил, она показала хорошие результаты по функции потерь.

***10646/16384 [==================>...........] - ETA: 1:19 - loss: 0.0261 - reconstruction_loss: 0.0119.***

Функцию потерь использовал tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError() среднеквадратичную ошибку во время обучения.
После чего начал тестировать сеть, подавал на выход сети тестовые данные, после сжатия их восстанавливал и сравнивал. Для сравнения использовал несколько функций ошибки:

***Среднеквадратичная ошибка:  0.007688329071532628
Абсолютная ошибка:  0.06874919453193457
Средняя абсолютная процентная ошибка:  13.701648363186077
Косинусное сходство:  -0.98648834***

По данным цифрам видно, что результаты как бы отличные, но если посмотреть на график и оценить его визуально, сразу становится понятно, что что то не то.
[image: Ораньжевый график реальный сигнал, синий - востановленный]

Оранжевый график реальный сигнал, синий - восстановленный

Также решил посмотреть спектр данных сигналов (извините за качество, было лень убирать постоянную составляющую и размечать частоты):
1 график восстановленный сигнал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2 график реальный сигнал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыл добавить вопрос: Какую лучше использовать функцию потерь для обработки сигналов и почему цифры показывают отличные результаты, а на самом деле это не соответствует истине?

Comment: Единственное я не использовал функцию потерь коэффициент корреляции, но почитав я узнал что он не очень пригоден в качестве функции потерь.

Comment: для внесения дополнений в текст вопроса нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Если вы нормализуете входные данные (приводите к диапазону 0-1, например), то у вас данные  разного масштаба будут для модели выглядеть как одинаковые. Хотя тут явно не только амплитуда отличается. Тут нужно всё анализировать - как вы данные готовите, как рисуете, как сравниваете.